# Deleting account, help needed

Tags: support, status-completed, deletion, user-accounts, deleted-accounts

I would like to delete my account on MSE, but I dont know how to do it. Could anybody help me in this matter.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Please note that your answers remain if you delete your account, to prevent them being here you have to delete them manually (on your own).

Comment: I contact Stack Exchange many times and ask for instructions how to delete my account, but no one from MSE answered me what should I do. Where should I write and who I should to ask to delete my account?

Answer (score 8):

The help center contains [a page](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account) with instructions for how to do it.

Since you have significant contributions to the site, you [contact](https://math.stackexchange.com/contact) Stack Exchange and request the deletion of your account. You will be told what further actions you need to perform to ascertain that it's really your intention to have your account deleted, and when those are done, your account will be scheduled for deletion. The process may take a couple of days.

But please think carefully whether you *really* want to delete your account before doing anything rash.

Comment: I contact Stack Exchange many times and ask for instructions how to delete my account, but no one from MSE answered me what should I do.

Comment: Where should I write and who I should to ask to delete my account?

Comment: Deletion of accounts like yours (with some significant contributions) is something that is done by the company employees, not something we are involved in. You use the "contact us" link at the footer of the page (or the link from the help center) to contact the company. I suppose you have done that. Have you received any reply so far?

Comment: No I have not recieve any replay.

Comment: Aha. They're probably busy then and haven't yet had time to look at it. I've poked a community manager to take a look, but it will probably take a while nevertheless.

Comment: @FisiaiLusia: I sent you a reply a few minutes ago. I also started the 24-hour timer on your deletion request. Check out the banner on [your profile](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/110661/fisiailusia).

Comment: Thank you very much!